# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, datetimepicker, date-formatting

Yes, I know there a lot of topic with this question, I searched and saw a lot of them but I still can not fix my problem.

ERROR: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I am receiving data from a datagridview that is in a different form, i receive it and can display it just fine, but now i want to covert the data that are in String format to date format and display it on datetimepickers forms.

Receiving data:

```
    public EditObras(string id, string NomeObra, string idCliente, string DataPLevantamento, string DataRLevantamento, string Estado, string DataRMateriais, string DataInicioObra, string DataConclusao, string DataVestoria, string Obs, string Prompor, string Levantpor, string executpor)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label4.Text = (string)id;
            textBox1.Text = (string)NomeObra;
            textBox2.Text = (string)idCliente;
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(DataPLevantamento, "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
            // textBox3.Text = (string)DataPLevantamento;
            textBox4.Text = (string)DataRLevantamento;
            comboBox1.Text = (string)Estado;
            textBox5.Text = (string)DataRMateriais;
            textBox6.Text = (string)DataInicioObra;
            textBox7.Text = (string)DataConclusao;
            textBox8.Text = (string)DataVestoria;
            textBox12.Text = (string)Obs;
            textBox9.Text = (string)Prompor;
            textBox10.Text = (string)Levantpor;
            textBox11.Text = (string)executpor;
}
```

I get the error on this line:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(DataPLevantamento, "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

The "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy" format, is the one im using, i got the format with this way, just to see what the format is:

```
string datePattern = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
        textBox1.Text = datePattern;
```

Value of DataPLevantamento is a data like this:

> 30 de outubro de 2016

Exception stack:

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=A cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como valor DateTime válido.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       em System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
       em System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)
       em GestãodeobrasGasFenosa.EditObras..ctor(String id, String NomeObra, String idCliente, String DataPLevantamento, String DataRLevantamento, String Estado, String DataRMateriais, String DataInicioObra, String DataConclusao, String DataVestoria, String Obs, String Prompor, String Levantpor, String executpor) em C:\Users\BugDroid\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GestãodeobrasGasFenosa\GestãodeobrasGasFenosa\EditObras.cs:line 26
       em GestãodeobrasGasFenosa.Form1.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) em C:\Users\BugDroid\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GestãodeobrasGasFenosa\GestãodeobrasGasFenosa\Form1.cs:line 606
       em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellDoubleClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       em System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       em System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       em System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       em GestãodeobrasGasFenosa.Program.Main() em C:\Users\BugDroid\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GestãodeobrasGasFenosa\GestãodeobrasGasFenosa\Program.cs:line 19
       em System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       em System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       em Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       em System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       em System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Well, what is the *value* you're trying to parse?

Comment: Please add the string value of `DataPLevantamento` to the question and tell us your actual value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Then you can probably remove about 90% of your code, because the `DateTime.ParseExact("Value of DataPLevantamento", "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy", (Value of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), DateTimeStyles.None)` question should be solvable regardless of context.

Comment: What are you passing to DataPLevantamento ?? 
You didnt answer @LasseV.Karlsen , asked you a sample of data you are passing as string there.
Also, you should consider passing a class to that constructor.
Something like :
public EditObras(Obras obra)

Comment: what the value of `DataPLevantamento` ?

Comment: Are you sure that `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` are the same? (since you use both in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way using custom culture

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT"); 
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(DataPLevantamento, "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy", 
                        culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: thats great happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the actual `CultureInfo`
The `CultureInfo` needs to be equal to yours,
so you must create a new `CultureInfo` variable.

I guessed that this language were Portuguese.

```
string DataPLevantamento = "30 de outubro de 2016";
    var provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT"); 
    string result = DateTime.ParseExact(DataPLevantamento,
                        "d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy",
                        provider,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: @BugDroid777 Can you send the exception stack trace please ? This is weird, as it works of .NET Fiddle

Comment: Added the post, i think thats what you asked for.

Comment: @BugDroid777 do you get the same error when executing exactly the code of this answer or when you try to use the answer in your code?